# PIC18F47K42 I2C Slave MCC code incrementing register by accident

Tags: pic, i2c, microchip, mplabx

Disclaimer:

I have submitted a forum post on Microchip as well as the forum appears to have issues with me and to increase the pool of possible answers I thought of posting here with as much detail as I could.

Issue:

Using MPLABX 5.10, MCC (Microchip Code Configurator plugin) 3.75 with I2C Driver version 2.11, XC8 v 2.00

MCC generated I2C Slave code is incrementing data address pointer when it shouldn't

Reproduction:

Run MCC with PIC18F47K42 project and add I2C slave and generate provides the code below (I have added some debug uart stuff hence the `queue_enqueue` calls):

```
void I2C1_ISR(void)
{

    uint8_t I2C1_data = 0x55;
    if ((I2C1STAT1bits.RXBF) || (PIR2bits.I2C1RXIF))
    {
        PIR2bits.I2C1RXIF = 0;
        I2C1_data = I2C1RXB;
        queue_enqueue(&uart_queue, "1");
    }
    if (1 == I2C1STAT0bits.R)
    {

        if (I2C1PIRbits.PCIF)
        {
            I2C1PIRbits.PCIF = 0;
            PIR3bits.I2C1IF = 0;
            I2C1STAT1bits.CLRBF = 1; //clear I2C1TXB and TXBE
            I2C1CNT = 0xFF;
            queue_enqueue(&uart_queue, "2");
        }
        if (I2C1ERRbits.NACKIF)
        {
            I2C1ERRbits.NACKIF = 0;
            PIR3bits.I2C1EIF = 0;
            I2C1STAT1bits.CLRBF = 1; //clear I2C1TXB and TXBE
            I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_READ_COMPLETED);
            queue_enqueue(&uart_queue, "3");
        }
        else if (PIR3bits.I2C1TXIF)
        {
            PIR3bits.I2C1TXIF = 0;
            // callback routine should write data into I2C1TXB
            I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_READ_REQUEST);
            queue_enqueue(&uart_queue, "4");
        }
        if (I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF)
        {
            I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF = 0;
            PIR3bits.I2C1IF = 0;
            queue_enqueue(&uart_queue, "5");
        }

    }
    else if ((I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF))
    {
        I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF = 0;
        PIR3bits.I2C1IF = 0;
        // callback routine should prepare to receive data from the master
        I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_REQUEST);
        queue_enqueue(&uart_queue, "6");
    }
    else
    {
        I2C1_slaveWriteData = I2C1_data;

        queue_enqueue(&uart_queue, "7");
        if (I2C1PIRbits.PCIF)
        {
            I2C1PIR = 0;
            PIR3bits.I2C1IF = 0;
            I2C1STAT1bits.CLRBF = 1;
            I2C1CNT = 0xFF;
            queue_enqueue(&uart_queue, "8");
        }

        // callback routine should process I2C1_slaveWriteData from the master
        I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_COMPLETED);
    }
    I2C1CON0bits.CSTR = 0;

}
```

eeprom simulated code MCC also provides:

```
    static uint8_t EEPROM_Buffer[] ={
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
        0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
        0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f,
        0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f,
        0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f,
        0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f,
        0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f,
        0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7f,
    };

    static uint8_t eepromAddress = 0;
    static uint8_t eepromData = 0x55;
    static uint8_t slaveWriteType = SLAVE_NORMAL_DATA;


    switch (i2c1_bus_state)
    {
    case I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_REQUEST:
        // the master will be sending the eeprom address next
        slaveWriteType = SLAVE_DATA_ADDRESS;
        break;


    case I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_COMPLETED:

        switch (slaveWriteType)
        {
        case SLAVE_DATA_ADDRESS:
            eepromAddress = I2C1_slaveWriteData;
            break;


        case SLAVE_NORMAL_DATA:
        default:
            // the master has written data to store in the eeprom
            EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++] = I2C1_slaveWriteData;
            if (sizeof (EEPROM_Buffer) <= eepromAddress)
            {
                eepromAddress = 0; // wrap to start of eeprom page
            }
            break;

        }

        slaveWriteType = SLAVE_NORMAL_DATA;
        break;

    case I2C1_SLAVE_READ_REQUEST:
        if (I2C1STAT1bits.TXBE)
        {
            I2C1TXB = EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++];
        }
        if (sizeof (EEPROM_Buffer) <= eepromAddress)
        {
            eepromAddress = 0; // wrap to start of eeprom page

        }
        break;

    case I2C1_SLAVE_READ_COMPLETED:
    default:;

    } // end switch(i2c1_bus_state)

}
```

Set the eepromAddress to 0x00 by writing one byte to slave

i.e.

`[SLAVE ADDR WRITE] [0x00]`

[image: Slave address WRITE and 1 byte 0x00]

Then read 8 bytes supposedly starting from register 0x00

i.e.

`[SLAVE ADDR READ] [B0] [B1] [B2] ...`

[image: Master read from slave after setting address to 0 in first I2C command]

As the "EEPROM" data should match the address I would expect the data 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 etc.... Instead I get 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 so it looks like eepromAddress has incremented somewhere by accident.

Looking at my UART output for `[SLAVE ADDR WRITE] [0x00]` I got:

```
6
1
7
7
8
```

Which means

```
6 (I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_REQUEST)
1 (I2C1_data = I2C1RXB)
7 (I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_COMPLETED))
7 (I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_COMPLETED))
8 (WRITE STOP)
```

What is see wrong is that it is calling I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_COMPLETED) twice when it should only be once as I only want to set the eepromAddress and not set any data. I.e. it will be going into SLAVE_NORMAL_DATA when it should only go into SLAVE_DATA_ADDRESS, and therefore incrementing eepromAddress in the line `EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++] = I2C1_slaveWriteData`

```
    switch (slaveWriteType)
    {
    case SLAVE_DATA_ADDRESS:
        eepromAddress = I2C1_slaveWriteData;
        break;


    case SLAVE_NORMAL_DATA:
    default:
        // the master has written data to store in the eeprom
        EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++] = I2C1_slaveWriteData;
        if (sizeof (EEPROM_Buffer) <= eepromAddress)
        {
            eepromAddress = 0; // wrap to start of eeprom page
        }
        break;

    }
```

The same thing also happens with continuous read

First read (8 bytes)

[image: First read]

Second read (8 bytes)

[image: Second read]

Note that 0x09 is missing in the second read

Debugging with UART it appears that I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_READ_REQUEST) is called nine times instead of eight times.

Has any one else been able to confirm this?
Is it a bug with MCC I2C driver for this PIC?
Is there an easy work around to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MCC code generates an interrupt function with a rather large else {} statement that it will enter on STOP as well as when BYTE RECEIVED and call WRITE_COMPLETE.

The receive code was changed to:

```
void I2C1_ISR(void)
{
    uint8_t I2C1_data = 0x55;
    unsigned char byte_received = 0; // new line
    :
    if ((I2C1STAT1bits.RXBF) || (PIR2bits.I2C1RXIF))
    {
        PIR2bits.I2C1RXIF = 0;
        I2C1_data = I2C1RXB;
        byte_received = 1;        
    }
    :
    else if ( byte_received ) // edited
    {
        I2C1_slaveWriteData = I2C1_data;

        // callback routine should process I2C1_slaveWriteData from the master
        I2C1_StatusCallback(I2C1_SLAVE_WRITE_COMPLETED);
    }
    else if (I2C1PIRbits.PCIF) // moved this out of the else if
    {
        I2C1PIR = 0;
        PIR3bits.I2C1IF = 0;
        I2C1STAT1bits.CLRBF = 1;
        PIR3bits.I2C1TXIF = 0;
        I2C1CNT = 0xFF;

    }
```

The interrupt manager was missing interrupt for I2C error flags - not sure if this was the cause of transmit as I gave up and ended up using the following example code here:

https://mplabxpress.microchip.com/mplabcloud/example/details/519

i.e.

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "i2c1.h"
#include "mcc.h"

#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x50 // this is the shifted address!

uint8_t EEPROM_Buffer[0x80] ={
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
    0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f,
    0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f,
    0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f,
    0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f,
    0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f,
    0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7f
};
uint8_t dataAddressByte = 0;
volatile uint8_t eepromAddress = 0;

void I2C1_Initialize(void)
{
    I2C1ADR0 = I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS; // Slave address 
    I2C1ADR1 = I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS;
    I2C1ADR2 = I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS;
    I2C1ADR3 = I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS;

    I2C1CON1 = 0x00; // CSD Clock Stretching enabled; ACKDT Acknowledge; ACKCNT Not Acknowledge;  
    I2C1CON2 = 0x00; // ABD enabled; SDAHT 300 ns; BFRET 8 I2C Clocks; FME disabled;
    I2C1CLK = 0x00; // Slave doesn't use I2CCLK
    I2C1CNT = 0x00;
    I2C1CON0 = 0x00; // CSTR Enable clocking; S Cleared by hardware after Start; MODE four 7-bit address; 

    PIR2bits.I2C1RXIF = 0;
    PIR3bits.I2C1TXIF = 0;
    PIR3bits.I2C1IF = 0;
    I2C1PIRbits.PCIF = 0;
    I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF = 0;

    PIE2bits.I2C1RXIE = 1;
    PIE3bits.I2C1TXIE = 1;
    PIE3bits.I2C1IE = 1;
    I2C1PIEbits.PCIE = 1;
    I2C1PIEbits.ADRIE = 1;

    I2C1CON0bits.EN = 1;
}

void I2C1_ISR(void)
{
    if ((PIR3bits.I2C1IF == 1) || (PIR2bits.I2C1RXIF == 1) || (PIR3bits.I2C1TXIF == 1))
    {
        if (I2C1STAT0bits.SMA == 1)
        {
            if (I2C1STAT0bits.R == 1)
            {
                if ((I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF == 1) && (I2C1STAT0bits.D == 0))
                {
                    I2C1CNT = sizeof (EEPROM_Buffer);
                    I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF = 0;
                    I2C1PIRbits.SCIF = 0;
                    I2C1CON0bits.CSTR = 0;
                    if (I2C1STAT1bits.TXBE == 1)
                    {
                        I2C1TXB = EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++];
                    }
                }
                if ((PIR3bits.I2C1TXIF == 1) && (I2C1STAT0bits.D == 1))
                {
                    if (I2C1CNT)
                    {
                        if (eepromAddress < sizeof (EEPROM_Buffer))
                        {
                            I2C1TXB = EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            eepromAddress = 0;
                            I2C1TXB = EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++];
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        eepromAddress = 0;
                    }
                    I2C1CON0bits.CSTR = 0;
                }
            }
            if (I2C1STAT0bits.R == 0)
            {
                if ((I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF == 1) && (I2C1STAT0bits.D == 0))
                {
                    I2C1PIRbits.ADRIF = 0;
                    I2C1PIRbits.SCIF = 0;
                    I2C1PIRbits.WRIF = 0;
                    I2C1STAT1bits.CLRBF = 1;
                    I2C1CON0bits.CSTR = 0;
                }
                if ((PIR2bits.I2C1RXIF == 1) && (I2C1STAT0bits.D == 1))
                {
                    if (dataAddressByte == 0)
                    {
                        eepromAddress = I2C1RXB;
                        I2C1PIRbits.WRIF = 0;
                        dataAddressByte = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (eepromAddress <= sizeof (EEPROM_Buffer))
                        {
                            while (I2C1STAT1bits.RXBF == 0);
                            EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++] = I2C1RXB;
                            I2C1PIRbits.WRIF = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            eepromAddress = 0;
                            EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++] = I2C1RXB;
                            I2C1PIRbits.WRIF = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    I2C1CON0bits.CSTR = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (I2C1PIRbits.PCIF)
            {
                I2C1PIRbits.PCIF = 0;
                I2C1PIRbits.SCIF = 0;
                I2C1PIRbits.CNTIF = 0;
                I2C1PIRbits.WRIF = 0;
                I2C1STAT1bits.CLRBF = 1;
                I2C1CNT = 0;
                dataAddressByte = 0;
                eepromAddress = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (PIR3bits.I2C1EIF == 1)
    {
        if (I2C1ERRbits.NACKIF)
        {
            I2C1ERRbits.NACKIF = 0;
            I2C1STAT1bits.CLRBF = 1;
            dataAddressByte = 0;
            eepromAddress = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Interrupt manager must also contain

```
if(PIE3bits.I2C1EIE == 1 && PIR3bits.I2C1EIF == 1)
{
    I2C1_ISR();
}    
else if(PIE3bits.I2C1IE == 1 && PIR3bits.I2C1IF == 1)
{
    I2C1_ISR();
}   
else if(PIE2bits.I2C1RXIE == 1 && PIR2bits.I2C1RXIF == 1)
{
    I2C1_ISR();
}    
else if(PIE3bits.I2C1TXIE == 1 && PIR3bits.I2C1TXIF == 1)
{
    I2C1_ISR();
}
```